# Nginx as internal forward proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse

- I have two servers, a proxy server running nginx, and a backend application server
- From the outside, everything works as expected.
- From the backend, I can access any outside server.
- When trying to access the very website from the backend (e.g. wget https://www.my-server-name.com) server, it leads to a timeout.

This is my configuration:

```html
server {
    listen 172.25.9.64:80;
    server_name www.my-server-name.com;
    root /dev/null;
    return 301 https://www.my-server-name.com$request_uri;
}

limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=data:10m;

server {
    listen 172.25.9.64:443 ssl;
    server_name www.my-server-name.com;
    root /var/www;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/server.ca-bundle;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.25.166.68:60936/;
        proxy_redirect default;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        include    /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply had to add the corresponding IPs to /etc/hosts.